# Is it possible to persist model validation errors and send it to another method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is to pass group of models through single view model to controller. I did this using `html.beginform` and passed this group to single method in controller. I want to save these model data in  DB. So I called different methods from that single method and saved data.

Problem is I am only returning view in main method. That's why validations that I have done for each model are not getting displayed when model is not valid. I validated models in controller using `TryValidateObject` but errors are not getting displayed in view because I cannot return view from multiple methods.

Code:

```
public ActionResult mthdSaveAllData(MdlViewmodel mdlviewmodel)
{
       mdlviewmodel.mdlviewmodel1status= mthdSaveModel1Data(mdlviewmodel);
       mdlviewmodel.mdlviewmodel2status= mthdSaveModel2Data(mdlviewmodel);
       mdlviewmodel.mdlviewmodel3status= mthdSaveModel2Data(mdlviewmodel);

       return View(mdlviewmodel);
}
```

All three methods return string as status if it's added or not as I can't return view from these 3.

In each method, I am validating model object like this.

```
public string mthdSaveModel1Data()
{
       ModelState.Clear();

       if (TryValidateModel(mdlviewmodel.mdlviewmodel1))
       {
              // some code here
       }

       return status; 
}
```

I have used `html.validationfor` in the view. But it's not getting displayed because I am not returning view from that particular method. I want to know if there is any way to persist validation errors and send it to main method?

(I tried to validate form using jquery but it didn't help. I have multiple submit buttons in view)

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you clearing the model state at all?

Comment: Because while validating object of model using TryValidateObject, It was giving me error to validate a single object. So I found a solution that says you should clear model state before using TryValidateObject. @Jeremy Lakeman

Comment: This is a controller action? In which case validation should have already run immediately after model binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre clearing ModelState for each method so it will display validationsummary only if last validation is false.

Use ModelState.IsValid or add ModelState errors manually for each validation

ModelState.AddModelError(propName,errorMessage);